# Как сделать для каждого страницы отдельную header в битриксе?

Tags: битрикс, header

Как сделать в Битриксе , чтобы на главной странице другой хедер а на другие страницы другой хедер.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вообще как написали про создание нескольких хедеров не совсем корректно.
Правильнее будет создать отдельные шаблоны сайтов. И повесить на них условия.
Зато в каждом шаблоне будет строго по своему css и js, а так же по одному хедеру и не нужно будет плодить 100500 костылей

Comment: На крайний случай можно и в рамках одного шаблона в файле шаблона header.php выполнять только include разных шапок в зависимости от текущей страницы, но вариант с разными шаблонами разумнее, хотя точной инфы для чего это всё мы не знаем.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ... у меня получилось)

Answer (score 0):

Сделай несколько отдельных хэдеров и подключай тот хэдер который нужен.
В моем случае я сделал два разных хэдера

```
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header2.php");
```

в нем соответственно

```
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog2.php");
```

вот еще [разные хэдеры](https://toster.ru/q/192093)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72177/discussion-on-answer-by-ziber-minsk-------h).